# How to send XML formatted POST DATA to external URL from CakePHP

Tags: xml, forms, api, cakephp, post

I am using CakePHP to write an application that consumes data from a webservice.  The webservice API is telling me I need to send my POST DATA as XML, like this:

```
<Request>
    <Key>abcd123</Key>
    <Param1>myval</Param1>
</Request>
```

How can I achieve this with CakePHP please?  I have tried something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create(Model, array('url' => 'https://myprovider/API/myuserid'));
echo $this->Form->input('Key', array('value'=> 'abcd123'));
echo $this->Form->input('Param1', array('value'=> 'myval'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

but how can I turn the POST array into xml before I submit?

Many thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: The key google term you're looking for is "Web Service Client".  I expect you'll need to find/provide the WSDL for that specific web service, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HttpSocket in CakePHP for sending POST array as xml

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
App::uses('Xml', 'Utility');
$http = new HttpSocket();
$http->configAuth('Basic', 'user', 'password'); //optional, if needs authentication
$xml_data = Xml::fromArray($this->request->data);
$xml_string = $xml_data->asXML();
$http->post('https://myprovider/API/myuserid', $xml_string);
```